# How to continue to the next iteration using let in Racket?

Tags: racket

I am trying to modify the code from bellow so that when `(when (= i 6) (loop (+ 1 i)))` appears the loop to move to the next iteration without continuing doing with the "do stuff" part.

```
(let loop ([i 0])
  (cond
    [(= i 10) (printf "end\n")]
    [else
     (when (= i 6) (loop (+ 1 i)))
       (define x (+ 1 2)) ; do stuff
       (printf "~a\n" i)
       (loop (+ 1 i))]))
```

Basically what I'm trying to obtain is something similar to "continue" from C# (like the code from bellow), but using let in Racket:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    if (i == 6) 
    {
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

If that's not possible (or recommended) in Racket, what can I use as an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite without `continue` by negating the condition:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    if (i != 6) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

then as `while` instead of `for`:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) 
{
    if (i != 6) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    i += 1;
}
```

and then this has almost exactly the same form:

```
(let loop ([i 0])
  (when (< i 10)
    (unless (= i 6)
      (printf "~a\n" i))
    (loop (+ 1 i))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired effect by adding one extra case to the `cond` expression. This is equivalent to your C# example:

```
(let loop ([i 0])
  (cond [(= i 10) (printf "end\n")]
        [(= i  6) (loop  (add1 i))]
        [else
         ; do some other stuff
         (printf "~a\n" i)
         (loop (add1 i))]))
```

You can "do stuff" after each condition, as long as the last expression is either the exit to the recursion or the recursive call - just remember that only the value of the last expression will be returned, and if you need to pass values to the next iteration, you'll need to add parameters to the recursive call.